# which test to use when the number of years is ranked?

Tags: anova, manova

Please help.i am trying to test whether there is a sig. difference when number of years of experience is grouped by ranking..

for example, 
a respondent ranks himself 1 under experience; the scoring guide is from 1 to 5

can i use ANOVA or do i need another test here?